# Compiler Weirdness with Libero.FusionCharts

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am using the CodePlex free Libero.FusionCharts libray as a better Yahoo.FusionCharts. According to the [documentation](http://liberofusioncharts.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Single%20Series%20Chart,%20adding%20data%20by%20DataSource&referringTitle=Documentation), I added an FChart control that acts as a placeholder for the chart.

```
<%@ Register Assembly="Libero.FusionCharts" Namespace="Libero.FusionCharts.Control" TagPrefix="fcl" %>
<fcl:FChart runat="server" ID="chtProductSales" Width="530" Height="300" />
```

I then do the following in the Page Load:

```
    MSColumn3DLineDYChart oChart = new MSColumn3DLineDYChart();

    // Set properties
    oChart.Background.BgColor = "ffffff";
    oChart.Background.BgAlpha = 50;
    oChart.ChartTitles.Caption = "Response Time";

    // Set a template
    oChart.Template = new Libero.FusionCharts.Template.OfficeLightTemplate();

    ObjectDataSource ods = new ObjectDataSource();
    ods.SelectMethod = "GetCenterETAPTA";
    ods.TypeName = "reportingDB";

    DataView dv = (DataView)ods.Select();
    dv.Sort = "ChartSort ASC";

    DataTable dt = dv.ToTable();
    oChart.DataSource = dt;
    oChart.DataCategoryTextField = "HOC";
    oChart.DataSeriesTextField = "NOC";
    oChart.DataSeriesValueField = "Club";

    // Link the WebControl and the Chart
    // FChart chart = (FChart) Page.FindControl(this.chtProductSales.ClientID);

    chtProductSales.ShowChart(oChart);
    // chart.ShowChart(oChart);
```

On the line chtProductSales, it's supposed to connect with the webcontrol. The compiler says:

> Error  1   The name 'chtProductSales' does not exist in the current context

However,  I can do Intellisense and get this.chtProductSales! What is wrong with the compiler? I tried a FindControl call with the same results. The documentation says this all I need:

```
// Link the WebControl and the Chart
chtProductSalles.ShowChart(oChart);
```

Their shipped example works. What is going on?

Comment: Do you have any warnings as well?

Comment: Did you call the FChart placeholder for the chart you added in the designer, "chtProductSales" ?

Comment: Yes, the line of code won't show up here <fcl:FChart runat="server" ID="chtProductSales" Width="530" Height="300" />

Comment: The thins is that it shows up in Intellisense and has that property chtProductSales.ShowChart(oChart);

Comment: Is there a xyz.designer.cs file for your page?

Comment: Nope, that could be it!

Comment: There is no designer file as it is, and has to stay, as a Web Site project. I notice their example has designer file though.

Comment: I guess it has to be a Web Application.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that this control does not work if you put it inside any ASP.NET Panel, so avoid putting this inside any Panel control etc and try.